# How I get the roles of the discord server in dc oAuth2?

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0, discord

I want to make a Discord login, but want to check if he is in my Server so I wanted to do an API call using the oAuth2 code etc.

here is the Request code:

```js
    getGuildsRole(code, userId, guildId) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.clear();
            const options = {
                method: 'POST'
            };
            let params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('client_id', this.config.client_id);
            params.append('client_secret', this.config.client_secret);
            params.append('code', code);
            params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
            params.append('scope', 'identify');
            params.append('redirect_uri', this.config.callback_url);
            options.body = params;
            await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', options)
                .then(async response => {
                    let x = await response.json();
                    var user
                    await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/v7/guilds/' + guildId + '/members/' + userId, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${x.access_token}`
                        }
                    }).then(async res => {
                        user = await res.json();
                        resolve(user);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        reject(err);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
```

The bot permissions are: Identify, E-Mail, Guilds. 
And I thinked with Guilds you can get the roles etc, but you can't I did go throw the API of Discord but it wasn't really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a extra bot which checks the guild roles by typing an command ;D